# How do I minimize the size of a Flutter Web Release? Is the NOTICES File required?

Tags: flutter, hosting, flutter-web

My `web` folder after building my Flutter Web app comes to 5.4MB which isn't too bad, but I might as well optimize.

I was wondering if anybody has any tips outside the obvious(removing unnecessary packages), to minimize the file size? I'll be hosting on Firebase.

Also, there is a `NOTICES` file which is about 1MB filled with random licenses/copyright disclaimers, are there any consequences to deleting this?

Is `flutter build web` all you do to build a release version? Is there anything else that should be done other than `flutter clean`?

Comment: There is no consequence to deleting the notices file nor is there much consequence to keeping it. `flutter build web` is all you need to do and it already does minification. `flutter clean` has no effect on how a release build is built and running it will do nothing for you that affects the final result. There isn't much you're going to be able to do to reduce the web app size besides reducing asset size. Please specify why you want to reduce the package size.

Comment: Great thanks that will free up some room, I’ll delete the notices file. I just wanted to reduce website size for fastest loading times but after some research I don’t think 5mb is bad, loads pretty much instant on my mobile data and wifi. I will run some tests when I deploy.

Comment: Deleting the notices file will not affect loading times as it's never requested. Read the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices) for optimizing flutter web. Deferred loading is very useful. Be careful when measuring loading times about caching. Flutter web apps almost never load quickly in my experience unless they're cached.

Comment: Great link and info thank you, just what I was looking for. I’ll be doing some more research! That Flutter Gallery app loads pretty much instantly.

Comment: @AugustKimo what was your Google Speed Test score for the website?

Answer (score 3):

According to flutter document, There is a option available for all platforms
but not available for **web** so far. [Read the full document](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/app-size#reducing-app-size)

**This command will help you to get a minimized size of build except web**

```
flutter build apk --analyze-size
flutter build appbundle --analyze-size
flutter build ios --analyze-size
flutter build linux --analyze-size
flutter build macos --analyze-size
flutter build windows --analyze-size
```